# Does each Map have its own thread?

Tags: mapreduce

Does each Map have its own thread? So, when we do splitting, we should split the task for as many Map function as we have processors available? Or there's some other way, besides threads, where we can run map functions in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're speaking about hadoop mapreduce implementation. Also, I assume you're speaking about cores workload.

For the intro, the number of map tasks for a given job is derived from the number of input data splits. Then, those tasks are scheduled to task nodes, where mappers are started, up to `mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` per node. This configuration paramether may differ for different nodes, for example in case of different computational power. I'll add an illustration from one of my other answers on SO:

[image: map tasks flow]

The [mappers](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html) by default, runs in a different JVM and there can be multiple JVMs running at any particular instance on a node, up to `mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum`. Those JVMs are recreated for each starting map task, or can be [reused](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html#Task+JVM+Reuse)
 for several consecutive runs. Won't dig in details, but this setting can also affect performance due to tradeoff between memory fragmentation and JVM instatiation overhead.

Proceeding to your question, amount of cores loaded by running JVMs is controlled by underlying OS, which does balance load and optimize computations. One can *expect* that different JVMs will be executed over different cores, if possible. One can expect performance degradation if number of mappers exceeds number of cores in general case. *I have skewed usecases where latter is not true.*

An example:

> Say you have job splitted in 100 map tasks, to be run on 2 task nodes with 2 cpu unit each, with `mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` equal to 2. Then, most of the time (except when waiting on mappers to start) your 100 elements task will be executed 4 at a given time, resulting (in average) in 50 tasks completed by each node.

And last, but not least. For mapper task, it is common to not to have CPU as bottleneck, but IO. In that case, it's not uncommon to get better results with many small on CPU machines vs a few servers huge on CPU.